# Why does the String not reset to null?

Tags: java, eclipse, authentication, client, server

im trying to create a login system with an server and a client. right now almost every thing works as i want to but there is one problem.. When i login with the client it sends the Username and password that the persion have inputed.if you login with correct information you will get logged in ofcurse. but if you put in a wrong username after the first persion logged in. it will still work.? heres an exempel.

//Correct Login info

```
Username: xoleo
Password: 123
 = LOGGED IN
```

//Wrong Login Info but still works after the correct login info

```
Username: xoleo123
Password: 123
 = LOGGED IN
```

//Wrong Login Info, this dosent work, and i dont know why the second way worked and this one dident..

```
Username: xoleo
Password: 1234
 = LOGGED FAILED
```

here is some code from the client side that sends the info after you press login:

```
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            send(username2.getText(), password2.getText(), InGame.address, InGame.port);
        }
    });

}

private void send(String name, String pass, String address, int port) {
    new LoginSend(name, pass, address, port);
}
```

Here is the code that for the 'send(String name, String pass, String address, int port)':

```
package ca.sidez.main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import ca.sidez.menu.InGame;
import ca.sidez.menu.Main;
import ca.sidez.menu.Main.STATE;
import ca.sidez.screen.ClientLogin;

public class LoginSend extends JFrame implements Runnable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JTextField txtMessage;
private Thread run, listen;
private ClientLogin clientLogin;

private boolean running = false;

public LoginSend(String name, String pass, String address, int port) {
    clientLogin = new ClientLogin(name, address, port);
    boolean connect = clientLogin.openConnection(address);
    if (!connect) {
        System.err.println("Connection failed!");
        System.out.println("Connection failed!");
    }
    System.out.println("Försöker att ansluta til " + address + ":" + port + ", username: " + name);
    String connection = "/u/" + name + "/u/" + "/p/" + pass + "/p/";
    clientLogin.send(connection.getBytes());
    running = true;
    run = new Thread(this, "Running");
    run.start();
}

public void run() {
    listen();
}

public void listen() {
    listen = new Thread("Listen") {
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                String message = clientLogin.receive();
                if (message.startsWith("/xp/")) {
                    InGame.Xp = message.split("/xp/|/xp1/")[1];
                    InGame.Gold = message.split("/g/|/e/")[1];
                    Main.State = STATE.LOADING;
                    System.out.println("Successfully Received Game Data To Player!");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    listen.start();
}
}
```

Here is some code from the server that will check the username and password:

```
    } else if (string.startsWith("/u/")) {
        user = string.split("/u/|/u/")[1];          
        pass = string.split("/p/|/p/")[1];

        passx = TextFile.readFile("/" + user + ".txt");
            System.out.println(user);
            System.out.println(pass);
            System.out.println(passx);

        if(pass.equals(passx)) {
            System.out.println(user);
            System.out.println(pass);
            System.out.println(passx);
            System.out.println("LOGGED IN");
            passx = "";
            user = null;
            pass = null;

        } else {
            System.out.println(user);
            System.out.println(pass);
            System.out.println(passx);
            System.out.println("LOGGED FAILED");
            passx = "";
            user = null;
            pass = null;
        }
```

The Server Console:

//this is the correct first one:

```
User input: xoleo
User input: 123
Server Checks: 123

LOGGED IN
```

//this is the wrong second time:

```
user input: xoleo
user input: 1234
correct password for the username: 123 (checks for a file with that name)
LOGGED FAILED
```

//this username doent exist, but the password is the old one

```
user input: leo
user input: 123
server checks: 123
LOGGED IN
```

Comment: what are `pass` and `passx` set to on the second try? print them in your server code

Comment: did you ever send the object around that sets pass and user or globally set the user and pass to null or only locally?

Comment: @Sidezpro then that seems like your problem, you should probably be passing them around as objects

Comment: @jgr208 how do you mean? passing them around as objects?

Comment: do you know anything about object orientation?

Comment: no? do you have any good sites about that? if you dont have the time to explain your self

Comment: if you don't know about if you should start off with some simpler stuff

Comment: its not hard in that way, but its me that wanted to try a new way to send info to a server. buut i can always about it on google :)

Comment: ohh, so thats what object orientation is, I know that ;D i will try it @jgr208

Answer (score 0):

Reference data type parameters, such as objects, are also passed into methods by value. This means that when the method returns, the passed-in reference still references the same object as before. However, the values of the object's fields can be changed in the method, if they have the proper access level.